# How to left join another nested table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, php-5.5

How can I left join another nested table?

The first query,

```
SELECT *
FROM category AS a
WHERE a.type = 'content'
```

Result,

```
category_id  type       code
1            content    content_1
2            content    content_2
3            content    content_3
```

Second query,

```
SELECT*
FROM content AS c

LEFT JOIN article_has_content AS x
ON x.content_id = c.content_id

WHERE x.article_id = '4'
```

Result,

```
category_id  value       article_id
1            xxa         4
2            xxb         4
```

The result I am after,

```
category_id  type       code          value
1            content    content_1     xxa
2            content    content_2     xxb
3            content    content_3     NULL
```

The third query,

```
SELECT*
FROM 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM category AS a
    WHERE a.type = 'content'
) a
LEFT JOIN b
(
    SELECT*
    FROM content AS c

    LEFT JOIN article_has_content AS x
    ON x.content_id = c.content_id

    WHERE x.article_id = '4'
) b
ON b.category_id = a.category_id
```

error,

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near '(
>       SELECT*
>       FROM content AS c
>
> ```
> LEFT JOIN article_has_content AS x
> ON x.content' at line 9
> ```

Comment: The error is a MySQL error so I removed the sql-server tag.

Comment: . . It would also help if you put your table definitions on SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were nearly right:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM category AS a
    WHERE a.type = 'content'
) a
LEFT JOIN                              -- the alias name here was wrong
(
    SELECT*
    FROM content AS c

    LEFT JOIN article_has_content AS x
    ON x.content_id = c.content_id

    WHERE x.article_id = '4'
) b                                    -- and you had the alias already here at the right position
ON b.category_id = a.category_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You put the alias after the subquery.  But in general, your query is just over-complicated.  I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT c.category_id, c.type, c.code, con.value
FROM category c left join
     content con
     on c.category_id = con.category_id left join
     article_has_content ahc
     on con.content_id = ahc.content_id and
        ahc.article_id = '4';
```

Comment: i get an error - `#1054 - Unknown column 'ahc.category_id' in 'on clause'`

Comment: @tealou . . . I had to guess which table has `category_id` because your question is unclear on this point.  It must be on `content` instead.

Comment: thanks for the edit but it does not output the null row which i need.

Comment: @tealou . . . I was wrong about the `left join`s as well.  Those are needed.  The key is to put the filtering on all-but-the-first table in the `on` clause.

Answer (score -1):

How about combining those 2 query, like below:

```
SELECT*
FROM content AS c

LEFT JOIN article_has_content AS x
ON x.content_id = c.content_id

LEFT JOIN category a ON a.category_id =  c.category_id AND a.type = 'content'

WHERE x.article_id = '4'
```

Comment: done that. it does not output the null which i need.